# Debounce makes PublishSubject emit only one item

Tags: android, fragment, rx-java2, debouncing, publishsubject

```
protected PublishSubject<Integer> onScrollS = PublishSubject.create();

public void onActivityCreated(...) {

        ...

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy == 0) return;
                Log.i("Rx", "onNext(" + dy + ")");
                onScrollS.onNext(dy);
            }
        });
        disposable = onScrollS
                .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // <-- this breaks everything
                .subscribe(this);
    }

    // the Fragment implements Consumer interface
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        Log.i("Rx", "Accept: " + integer);
        recyclerViewOnScrolled();
    }
```

When I add `.debounce` call to my onScrollS subject 
the `accept` method is called only once.

I can scroll and scroll then pause for ten seconds and nothing happens.

Anybody knows why ?

I tried something like this:

```
.debounce((Function<Integer, Observable<Integer>>) value - > {
    return Observable.just(value).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
})
```

And it works if I remove the `delay` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here may be a few problems:

- Subscribe on scroll events before adding OnScrollListener
- Add thread handler to Rx stream to be sure that you subscribe stream on IO thread and observe on Main thread
- Also you can add onNext implementation right away in subscribe method

```
    onScrollS
                .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Integer dy) throws Exception {
                        // TODO handle scroll event
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` fixed it but why do I need to move to another thread just to debounce these items ? Is it specified somewhere in documentation ?

Comment: Yes, debounce operates by default on the computation Scheduler so you have to be aware of that and handle subscribeOn/observerOn itself. It is also a good and recommended practice.